# How to get public storage path? (No SD card)

Tags: android, gmail

I have two apps, one is writing the file and other one (Gmail) is trying to attach that file. But now, the Gmail app gives the error of

> Permission denied for attaching the file.

I think I am storing the file in private directory that is `/data/data/PACKAGE/files/file.txt`
Where can i write the file so that Gmail app not give the error? 
I am attaching the file as;

```
String filelocation = "/data/data/com.example.xxxxxxxxx/files/file.txt";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
intent.setType("text/plain");
String message="File to be shared is " + file_name + ".";
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse( "file://"+filelocation));
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:xyz@gmail.com"));
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: @ianhanniballake I have added the <provider> tag but `android:name="android.support.v4.context.FileProvider"` gives the error that 'Unresolved package 'context''

Comment: That's because it is `content`, not `context`.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Noe `.FileProvider` is red. and giving `Unresolved class`.

Comment: It sounds like you didn't read [sharing files training](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing.html) in the answer and see the Note in the first section.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Kindly see the thread, I started it, facing a problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43316201/cannot-attach-empty-file-using-file-provider

Comment: @ianhanniballake Kindly.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43316201/cannot-attach-empty-file-in-gmail-using-file-provider?noredirect=1#comment73697247_43316201

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using static file path, I recommend to use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()` that will return you directory up to your public storage. Then you can make static path up to your private folder and merge with /filename.extension.

Comment: Gmail doesn't request the storage permission, so it doesn't have access to anything in `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Kindly guide me.

Comment: @Humty - your question is an exact duplicate. Look at the duplicate question and its answer.

Comment: @Okay Let me try using `FileProvider`. Will be back .